# "Bad Version of provider." while loading the Public key with RSACryptoServiceProvider

Tags: c#, rsa, encryption-asymmetric, rsacryptoserviceprovider

I am creating RSA key pair using `AsymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider` (`Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core`) and exporting the keys as shown below:

```
  AsymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider rsaGenKeys = AsymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(AsymmetricAlgorithmNames.RsaPkcs1);

  CryptographicKey keyPair = rsaGenKeys.CreateKeyPair(2048);
  byte[] privateKeyBlob = keyPair.Export(CryptographicPrivateKeyBlobType.Pkcs1RsaPrivateKey).ToArray();

  string privateKeyBlobStr = Convert.ToBase64String(privateKeyBlob);

  byte[] publicKeyBlob = keyPair.ExportPublicKey().ToArray();

  string pubilcKeyBlobStr = Convert.ToBase64String(publicKeyBlob);
```

Now, the receiver of this data happens to be a Silverlight app and is using `RSACryptoServiceProvider` (`System.Security.Cryptography`) to load this public key:

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaPublic = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
byte[] keyBlobBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(keyBlob);
rsaPublic.ImportCspBlob(keyBlobBytes);
```

Where keyBlob is the byte array having the public key.
The issue is when ImportCspBlob is called it throws exception saying "Bad Version of provider."

Comment: have you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. For some reason FxSSH did not like a public RSA key I generated. I had to use the RSA key in the https://github.com/Aimeast/FxSsh readme.